# Dojo data grid filter for multiple columns

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I want to filter all columns in the data grid based on `or` condition. 
For a single column(name) filter I tried below function and it's working properly.

```
grid.filter( {name: "*" + value + "*" } );
```

Now I want to use this filter for multiple columns on grid, I tried below code but that is not working:

```
grid.filter({name:"*" + value + "*"} || {solution:"*" + value + "*"});
```

Please help me with suitable code for multiple column filter on grid. I am using Dojo 1.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Create hidden column for filtering purposes and put in concatenated data you want to be filtered.

If your data for datastore are:

```
data=[
{ name: "smartphone", solution: "use iPhone instead iPod"},
{ name: "tablet",     solution: "use iPad instead iPod"},
{ name: "iPad",       solution: "use it"}
]
```

add column forFiltering with concatenated data of other columns:

```
data=[
{ name: "smartphone", solution: "use iPhone instead iPod", forFiltering: "smartphone use iPhone instead iPod"},
{ name: "tablet",     solution: "use iPad instead iPod",   forFiltering: "tablet use iPad instead iPod"},
{ name: "iPad",       solution: "use it",                  forFiltering: "iPad use it"}
]
```

and then do filtering on that column:

```
grid.filter({forFiltering:"*" + value + "*"});
```

Comment: Please give a coding example if you can.

Comment: @dori-naji  solution is for: 'condition1 and condition2', Swpno asks for: 'value is in field1 or in field2'

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand your question correctly, you can simply separate the two arguments for the filter with a comma. so instead of `grid.filter({name:"*" + value + "*"} || {solution:"*" + value + "*"});`

you should use `grid.filter({name:"*" + value + "*",solution:"*" + value + "*"} );`

you can check this working example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMQAa/805/)